# What is the best way to reuse the Lua parser?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, programming-languages, lua

I know how to embed Lua in other languages, but I would like to re-use ONLY the parser to parse code and give me the result as AST for instance. What is the easiest way of doing that with the Lua platform?

Thanks!

Comment: The lua parser doesn't generate an AST - the source code goes in one pass from text to bytecode

Comment: Does that mean what I want is impossible? The parser cannot be reused ?

Comment: What do you wish to do with an AST?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: reusing the lexer might still be enough to generate a description of the program structure.  Then, OP can construct an AST out of that.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: While the Lua parser doesn't generate an AST, why can't it be gutted and bent to produce one?  Surely that parser has the most accurate model of Lua around.

Comment: @IraBaxter: "why can't it be gutted and bent to produce one?" Who says it can't? That doesn't mean it'll be a particularly fruitful process, or that it wouldn't be faster to just translate the grammar into a parser using any number of available tools? It's not like Lua has complex grammar rules or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone already made an [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) grammar for the Lua language:

http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1178608849736/Lua.g

Or if you're using ANTLR v4:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/lua/Lua.g4

I've used ANTLR on a couple projects with good results.  It will generate a C (ANTLR v3) or C++ (ANTLR v2) parser including AST generation if you ask for it.

Comment: Why does v2 produce C++ while v3 produces C?

Comment: And interesting question.  v2 had several targets, including C++, Java, and C#.  v3 supports C, Java, C#, Python, and Objective C.  While it may be obvious why they added Python and Objective C, it's not so clear why they abandoned C++.  One ANTLR maintainer said several times that he'd write a C++ target for ANTLR v3, but never did.  Maybe others haven't tried because the cookie is wet (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/12/01/9930480.aspx).  How did the C++ target from v2 "disappear" from v3?  That's because they redesigned the target API to make it easier to add languages.

Comment: @PhoenixX_2: I have updated the link.  ANTLR folks broke many links on their site a while ago it seems.